# how to pass object to test method in laravel?

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

I have a class with the following signature:

```
class Service
{
    public function __construct(
        Class $a,
        Class $b,
        Class $c
    )
```

how can I get an instance of it in a test method? the call through the constructor throws the following error

```
Too few arguments to function Service::__construct(), 0 passed
```

but in the application itself, this class works, for example, in the command:

```
class ServiceCommand extends AbstractCommand
{
    protected $service;


    public function __construct(Service $service)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->service = $service;
    }
```

How to get an instance of the Service object in a phpunit test-method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **but in the application itself, this class works**

You need to understand Dependency injection and how the [Service container](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container) works in Laravel.

### How to get an instance of the Service object in a phpunit test-method

Two ways - one for feature testing, one for unit:

##### Feature

Use the service container to inject dependencies.

```
$this->service = $this-app->make(Service::class);
```

##### Unit

Mock your dependencies - read more about [mocking](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mocking#introduction)

```
$mockA = $this->createMock(Class::class);
// ...
$this->service = new Service($mockA...);
```

Comment: pls approve this answer, if it's helpfully for you :)